# Angle brackets in Python

Tags: python, scapy

I want to craft packets using scapy. When looking through the IP() class members I came across the following code idiom:

```
'fieldtype': {

    'frag': <Field (IP,IPerror).frag>, 
    'src': <Field (IP,IPerror).src>, 
    'proto': <Field (IP,IPerror).proto>, 
    'tos': <Field (IP,IPerror).tos>, 
    'dst': <Field (IP,IPerror).dst>, 
    'chksum': <Field (IP,IPerror).chksum>, 
    'len': <Field (IP,IPerror).len>, 
    'options': <Field (IP,IPerror).options>, 
    'version': <Field (IP,IPerror).version>, 
    'flags': <Field (IP,IPerror).flags>, 
    'ihl': <Field (IP,IPerror).ihl>, 
    'ttl': <Field (IP,IPerror).ttl>, 
    'id': <Field (IP,IPerror).id>}, 
    'time': 1465637588.477862, 
    'initialized': 1, 
    'overloaded_fields': {},
```

I am relatively new to Python. Can someone explain to me what purpose the angle brackets serve in each field type definition?

I have been trying to figure out this myself using the following documentation but got completely stuck.

[Scapy 2.3.1](https://fossies.org/dox/scapy-2.3.1/classscapy_1_1packet_1_1Packet.html#a9aa7631a8eba00ced779b9047e9fbe03)

Thanks

Comment: It's just string representation of object, not actual Python syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`repr` when applied to a `Field` instance uses the following definition for `__repr__` which is the source of the not Python syntax.

```
def __repr__(self):
    return "<Field (%s).%s>" % (",".join(x.__name__ for x in self.owners),self.name)
```