# What is the meaning of angle brackets in Python?

Tags: python, syntax, brackets

I found [the following lines](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/svm/liblinear.pyx#L27) in the scikit-learn package:

```
if is_sparse:
    problem = csr_set_problem(
            (<np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1, mode='c']>X.data).data,
            (<np.ndarray[np.int32_t,   ndim=1, mode='c']>X.indices).shape,
            (<np.ndarray[np.int32_t,   ndim=1, mode='c']>X.indices).data,
            (<np.ndarray[np.int32_t,   ndim=1, mode='c']>X.indptr).shape,
            (<np.ndarray[np.int32_t,   ndim=1, mode='c']>X.indptr).data,
            Y.data, (<np.int32_t>X.shape[1]), bias,
            sample_weight.data)
else:
    ...
```

All my searches for "angle brackets in Python" give answers about [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37762596/angle-brackets-in-python) or [decorator syntax](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators#I._angle_brackets_decorator_syntax), which I am pretty sure this is neither because it looks like actual logic.

What do the angle brackets in the above Python code do and where can I learn more about them?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is Cython's syntax for type casting/coercion. It is not plain Python. Notice the file extension is `.pyx`

You can learn more about them in the [documentation](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/language_basics.html#type-casting) for Cython.

Here's an example taken from the doc page:

```
cdef char *p, float *q
p = <char*>q
```

Using Cython is not uncommon with projects like `scikit-learn`, where one gains significant optimisations by mixing readable Python with blazing-speed C.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Cython documentation, about types](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/userguide/language_basics.html#statements-and-expressions).

Additionally you could note that the file extension is `.pyx` and on the top of the file there are `cimport` statements.