# Angle bracket notation in PySpark's Column<'FieldNameString'>

Tags: apache-spark-sql

The PySpark documentation for the [Column
class](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.4.1/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.Column.html) has formatting issues that make some of the examples hard to
read.  The Annex below contains its doc string, which to me seems clearer.  It shows typical
code patterns:

1. `Column<'TheColumnName'>` for a column within a `DataFrame`
   with column names or
2. `Column<...>` for a unnamed result of an arithmetic
   operation on a DataFrame column (which I presume is performed on each
   element within the column).

The angle brackets are not the same as the round brackets for
supplying arguments with which to instantiate an object of a class.
If it was, I would browse the `__init__` method to see what
information is encompassed by the object, and hence what it is
"supposed to be" and how it might be used.

The only thing I can find on angle brackets in Python pertains to
[Cython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43118694) rather than
Python proper.  Searching for angle brackets with PySpark or Apache
Spark hasn't yielded anything that looks relevant.

How should this syntax be interpretted?  Or is it supposed to be *not*
interpretted other than loosely as a Column object corresponding to
the field within the angle brackets?  If the latter, then unfortunately, I can't use that information to dig deeper into the host module's `column.py` source code in order to get insight into the object.

## Annex: Class `Column` doc string

```
class Column:
    """
    A column in a DataFrame.
    .. versionadded:: 1.3.0
    .. versionchanged:: 3.4.0
        Supports Spark Connect.

    Examples
    --------
    Column instances can be created by

    >>> df = spark.createDataFrame(
    ...      [(2, "Alice"), (5, "Bob")], ["age", "name"])

    Select a column out of a DataFrame
    >>> df.name
    Column<'name'>
    >>> df["name"]
    Column<'name'>

    Create from an expression

    >>> df.age + 1
    Column<...>
    >>> 1 / df.age
    Column<...>
    """
```